# Disable password authentication on SSH server on OS X Server 10.8

Tags: terminal, osx-server, ssh

I want to disable the password authentication of the SSH server on my OS X Server. this should be done in /etc/sshd_config, right? But I’m not sure which setting I should change…

Comment: it still doesn’t work. I don’t know, what I do wrong. Should I post any configs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As any BSD system you should toggle off some options in your sshd_config like I've described [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241197/how-to-disable-password-authentication-for-every-users-except-several):

```
UsePam yes # it will not be used
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
kbdInteractiveAuthentication no
```

Comment: I can’t find kbdInteractiveAutentication. The options have a # at the beginning of the line. Should I remove them?

Comment: the # sign before lines tells about default values. kbdInteractiveAutentication seems to be deprecated but may be used.

Comment: @SebastianSemmler is this answer is helpful for you?

Comment: no, still can login via password

Comment: You have to restart remote login

Comment: I am somewhat annoyed to discover that my upgrade to Yosemite caused sshd_config to have commented out the modifications I made to it (modifications similar to this) -- what about kbdInteractiveAuthentication? Should I add it or not?

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps, I was having trouble with this on 10.10 (Yosemite) and it turned out I was editing the wrong file.  `/etc/sshd_config` is the right one, not `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which is what I was trying based on what `man sshd_config` says:

```
SSHD_CONFIG(5)              BSD File Formats Manual             SSHD_CONFIG(5)

NAME
     sshd_config -- OpenSSH SSH daemon configuration file

SYNOPSIS
     /etc/ssh/sshd_config

DESCRIPTION
     sshd(8) reads configuration data from /etc/ssh/sshd_config ...
```

Comment: Since 10.11 `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` - right path

Comment: @Speakus this was a problem for me, as upgrading to 10.11 meant that password authentication was reenabled and I didn't catch it for a couple months.