# ssh_config changes not taking effect

Tags: ssh, launchd, high-sierra

My ultimate goal is to disable password login, as seen here:
[Disable password authentication on SSH server on OS X Server 10.8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/disable-password-authentication-on-ssh-server-on-os-x-server-10-8/84574#84574)

But I suspect the changes I'm making to /etc/ssh/ssh_config aren't taking effect. Here are my steps:

1. sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
2. Just change the port from 22 to 2222 with this line:
   Port 2222 (not commented out)
3. sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
4. That should stop the service and start it again, but it's still on port 22.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config for that