# How to change ssh port number when installed through MacPorts?

Tags: ssh, macports

I have OpenSSH installed via MacPorts on a macOS 10.14 system. I want to change the port its listening on to something other than 22, and have changed `/opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and uncommented the `Port` line like so:

```
Host *
  Port 12345
```

I then restarted OpenSSH with:

```
sudo port unload openssh
sudo port load openssh
```

However I can still only connect on port 22. How do I change the port properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always worth checking some of the related answers, [for example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304829/ssh-config-changes-not-taking-effect?rq=1), and it hadn't clicked for me at first.

You need to change `/opt/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. You've been amending the default port used by the client config.